# How to extract HTML data from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract certain elements from a block of webpages that I've extracted and put into a pandas column. I've tried lxml and can't get to pull out very specific phrases in text. What is the pythonistic way to go?
Tried this:

```
def scrape_details(s):
    results = requests.get(s)
    results2 = etree.parse(StringIO(str(results.content)), parser)
    return results2.xpath('//p')
df['data'] = df['URL'].map(lambda x: scrape_details(x))
```

Returned:

```
0   The Kingsley School https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/warwickshire/royal-leamington-spa/the-kingsley-school/    warwickshire    [[], [[]], [], [], [[], [], [], []], [], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[], [], []], [[], [<Element a at 0x7fd3c003fec0>, <Element a at 0x7fd3c0035a80>, <Element a at 0x7fd3c003fec0>, <Element a at 0x7fd3c0035a80>, <Element a at 0x7fd3c003fec0>, <Element a at 0x7fd3c0035a80>]], [[]], [[]], [[], []], [[]], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

What elements are you trying to extract? If its general HTML elements you could use the [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) python package. I just modified the generic parser class they provide near the bottom of the page a lil:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd








from html.parser import HTMLParser
from html.entities import name2codepoint


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parsed_html = []
        super().__init__()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.parsed_html.append(f"Start tag: {tag}")
        for attr in attrs:
            self.parsed_html.append(f"     attr: {attr}")

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.parsed_html.append(f"End tag  : {tag}")

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.parsed_html.append(f"Data     : {data.strip()}")

    def handle_comment(self, data):
        self.parsed_html.append(f"Comment  : {data.strip()}")

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        c = chr(name2codepoint[name])
        self.parsed_html.append(f"Named ent: {c}")

    def handle_charref(self, name):
        if name.startswith('x'):
            c = chr(int(name[1:], 16))
        else:
            c = chr(int(name))
        self.parsed_html.append(f"Num ent  : {c}")

    def handle_decl(self, data):
        self.parsed_html.append(f"Decl     : {data.strip()}")


def scrape_details(url):
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    html_text = requests.get(url).text
    parser.feed(html_text)
    return parser.parsed_html


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'URL': ['https://www.isc.co.uk/schools/england/warwickshire/royal-leamington-spa/the-kingsley-school/']})
df['data'] = df['URL'].map(lambda url: scrape_details(url))

for data in df['data']:
    print('\n'.join(data))
```

some of result:

```
Data     : 
Decl     : DOCTYPE html
Data     :
Start tag: html
     attr: ('lang', 'en')
Data     :
Start tag: head
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('charset', 'UTF-8')
End tag  : meta
Data     :
Start tag: title
Data     : The Kingsley School, Royal Leamington Spa - ISC
End tag  : title
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('name', 'robots')
     attr: ('content', 'index, follow')
End tag  : meta
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('rel', 'canonical')
     attr: ('href', '/schools/england/warwickshire/royal-leamington-spa/the-kingsley-school/')
End tag  : link
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('name', 'description')
     attr: ('content', 'Information about Royal Leamington Spa, The Kingsley School')
End tag  : meta
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('name', 'viewport')
     attr: ('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('name', 'format-detection')
     attr: ('content', 'telephone-no')
End tag  : meta
Data     :
Comment  : Google Tag Manager
Data     :
Start tag: script
Data     : (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TCCJT7P');
End tag  : script
Data     :
Comment  : End Google Tag Manager
Data     :
Start tag: script
     attr: ('src', '/bundles/upper?v=C-4SuuHJ23ObmSV6TVgJvlUZTwUHbE9Mit8bUEVmwIo1')
End tag  : script
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('href', '/bundles/site?v=_nmQ8YRQiebaCD8eMIdpKjF42e4TM9br-6hkul2424o1')
     attr: ('rel', 'stylesheet')
End tag  : link
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('rel', 'apple-touch-icon')
     attr: ('sizes', '180x180')
     attr: ('href', '/favicon/isc/apple-touch-icon.png')
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('rel', 'icon')
     attr: ('type', 'image/png')
     attr: ('sizes', '32x32')
     attr: ('href', '/favicon/isc/favicon-32x32.png')
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('rel', 'icon')
     attr: ('type', 'image/png')
     attr: ('sizes', '16x16')
     attr: ('href', '/favicon/isc/favicon-16x16.png')
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('rel', 'manifest')
     attr: ('href', '/favicon/isc/site.webmanifest')
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('rel', 'mask-icon')
     attr: ('href', '/favicon/isc/safari-pinned-tab.svg')
     attr: ('color', '#5bbad5')
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('name', 'msapplication-TileColor')
     attr: ('content', '#ffc40d')
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('name', 'msapplication-config')
     attr: ('content', '/favicon/isc/browserconfig.xml')
Data     :
Start tag: meta
     attr: ('name', 'theme-color')
     attr: ('content', '#ffffff')
Data     :
Start tag: script
Data     : var aId = 0; // mz values
                var sId = 0;
                var mID = 0;
End tag  : script
Data     :
Start tag: script
     attr: ('src', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js')
End tag  : script
Data     :
Start tag: link
     attr: ('href', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')
     attr: ('rel', 'stylesheet')
     attr: ('integrity', 'sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN')
     attr: ('crossorigin', 'anonymous')
Data     :
Start tag: script
     attr: ('type', 'application/ld+json')
Data     : {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "School",
  "name": "The Kingsley School",
  "url": "https://www.thekingsleyschool.co.uk/",
  "description": "Kingsley provides a friendly, supportive family environment where individuals are encouraged to enjoy learning, and to aim for and achieve
 excellence. Our principal aim is to enable all our pupils to fulfil their potential wherever it may lie, through our wide range of subjects, lively extra-c
urricular activities, small classes and highly effective pastoral care.\r\n",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressCountry": "England",
    "addressLocality": "Royal Leamington Spa",
    "streetAddress": "Beauchamp Avenue",
    "postalCode": "CV32 5RD",
    "telephone": "+44 (0)1926 425127"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": 52.2942769,
    "longitude": -1.5379113
  },
  "email": "schooloffice@kingsleyschool.co.uk"
}
End tag  : script

UPDATE:

specific terms I want to extract:

Head's name: Mr James Murphy-O'Connor (Principal)
ISC associations: HMC, IAPS, GSA, AGBIS, ISBA

Religious affiliation: Church in Wales

Day/boarding type: Day and Full Boarding

Gender profile: Boys and girls taught separately (diamond structure)
Size: 1236

Boys - age range & pupil numbers:

Day: 3 to 18 (522)

Boarding: 7 to 18 (150)

Sixth form: (156)

Girls - age range & pupil numbers:

Day: 3 to 18 (456)

Boarding: 7 to 18 (108)

Sixth form: (104)

...
```